# (Android) Share PNG from Drawable folder direct to WhatsApp

Tags: android, android-intent

I found the code for sharing text directly to WharsApp from my app:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
startActivity(sendIntent);
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
```

Now I want to share a PNG from my Drawable folder (R.drawable.image2share) directly to WhatsApp. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/drawable/image2share");
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
sendIntent.setType("image/png");
sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "send"));
```